# Text format and field profile

Tags: input-formats, users

I am working in Drupal 7.

I have a text-area in profile. I need the text area has a specific text format without editor but allows tags HTML.

The text format only is for the role "registered users", not for other roles and only in the text-area in the profile. This restriction is only for the field in profile.

If I have a role named "role test" that can edit articles and edit the profile, I need that the "role test" has not html tags in the text-area field in profile but the "role test" has editor in the content articles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "registered users" have permission to use that input format and "role test" does not have permission to use that input format. "role test" could have permissions for the editor format without having permissions for the input format for the profile field.

Comment: I have updated my question.  Thanks for your answer.